# Kotlin Koans Course View is not loading in the latest Android Studio

Tags: kotlin, intellij-plugin, android-studio-plugin

I updated the Edu Tools plugin and Android studio to the latest versions and tried. It's not loading the 'Course' view in the Project window.

Here is the IDE error message I got:

`com.jetbrains.edu.learning.projectView.CourseViewPane.installComparator(Ljava/util/Comparator;)V
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.jetbrains.edu.learning.projectView.CourseViewPane.installComparator(Ljava/util/Comparator;)V
    at com.jetbrains.edu.learning.projectView.CourseViewPane.createComponent(CourseViewPane.kt:78)
    at com.intellij.ide.projectView.impl.ProjectViewImpl.showPane(ProjectViewImpl.java:478)
    at com.intellij.ide.projectView.impl.ProjectViewImpl.viewSelectionChanged(ProjectViewImpl.java:576)
    at com.intellij.ide.projectView.impl.ProjectViewImpl.access$900(ProjectViewImpl.java:115)
    at com.intellij.ide.projectView.impl.ProjectViewImpl$5.selectionChanged(ProjectViewImpl.java:535)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor75.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.intellij.util.EventDispatcher.dispatch(EventDispatcher.java:99)
    at com.intellij.util.EventDispatcher.access$200(EventDispatcher.java:35)
    at com.intellij.util.EventDispatcher$2.invoke(EventDispatcher.java:79)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy111.selectionChanged(Unknown Source)
    at com.intellij.ui.content.impl.ContentManagerImpl.fireSelectionChanged(ContentManagerImpl.java:582)
    at com.intellij.ui.content.impl.ContentManagerImpl.addSelectedContent(ContentManagerImpl.java:395)
    at com.intellij.ui.content.impl.ContentManagerImpl$1.run(ContentManagerImpl.java:486)
    at com.intellij.ui.content.impl.ContentManagerImpl.lambda$setSelectedContent$1(ContentManagerImpl.java:499)
    at com.intellij.openapi.util.ExecutionCallback.setExecuted(ExecutionCallback.java:58)
    at com.intellij.openapi.util.ActionCallback.setDone(ActionCallback.java:72)
    at com.intellij.openapi.wm.impl.FocusManagerImpl.lambda$null$5(FocusManagerImpl.java:292)
    at com.intellij.util.ui.UIUtil.invokeLaterIfNeeded(UIUtil.java:2795)
    at com.intellij.openapi.wm.impl.FocusManagerImpl.lambda$null$6(FocusManagerImpl.java:290)
    at com.intellij.openapi.util.ActionCallback$ExecutedExecutionCallback.doWhenExecuted(ActionCallback.java:177)
    at com.intellij.openapi.util.ActionCallback.doWhenDone(ActionCallback.java:111)
    at com.intellij.openapi.wm.impl.FocusManagerImpl.lambda$_requestFocus$9(FocusManagerImpl.java:290)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:311)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:762)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:98)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:715)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:732)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.defaultDispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:822)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue._dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:650)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:366)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)`